# CRM 365 - Hide a sitemap Area

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Is any clean way to hide an area from the sitemap, other than reviewing many role privileges one by one and remove privilege completely. I would be ok with amount of work just that there is no one-to-one correlation between the privilege and the menu item and more important, is the fact some of the privileges has many ramifications and I don't want to affect existing functionality. It would be hard to track bugs in this case.

Comment: You mean sitemap or command bar(ribbon)?

Comment: I mean the the one technical called Area at the top of everything. Available through the sitemap editor. For command bar I can use the Ribbon Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to start with the logical grouping of necessary working entities (**SubArea**) under right **Group**, and ideally hence the main **Area**.

[image]

Let's say for example - Sales area should have Managers and Reps as Groups then classify the sub-areas for them individually for their needed entities. Then the navigation can be regulated with the help of identifying privileges specific for each persona and the navigation items can be controlled which hide the Group from others. [Read more](http://www.crmconsultants.co.uk/creating-a-role-based-sitemap-navigation-in-dynamics-crm/)

Or if it is tough to identify such dedicated persona privilege, then create a dummy entity just for sitemap regulation without breaking any existing implementation.

In UCI app world, you can spin a new App for each persona, so silo app with own sitemap and logical groups the way you want.

Comment: Hi Arun - you are perfectly right and should have been more specific. The way you describe it is the way I've implement it. My problem was with the "Settings" Area but I don't think is an easy answer to that because that area groups a number "generic" items and most of the time it will be at least one will keep that area visible for a user. Unless a very scale down role is implemented.

Comment: @Maf yes you’re right. Settings is little tricky - but extensions which stores custom entities maybe cleaned and added to a separate area if you want.